# Proper way of managing model data in Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, model, angular10

Let's say I want to create a simple tic-tac-toe game and i have model for the gameboard.
And my question is, where should i put logic for managing this board. For example.

```
export class Board{
  boardString: string;
  rows: string[];
  separator: string;

  constructor(boardString: string, separator: string = '|'){
    this.boardString = boardString;
    this.separator = separator;
    this.rows = this.boardString.split('|');
  }
}
```

```
// inside model class 
atIndex(index: number): string{
    const atCol = index % this.rows.length;
    const atRow = (index - atCol) / this.rows.length;
    return this.rows[atRow][atCol];
  }

isFinished(): boolean {
  // check if game is finished
}

getRow(index): string{
 return this.rows[index]
}
```

vs

```
// or in the Service
atIndex(index: number): string{
    const atCol = index % this.boardModel.rows.length;
    const atRow = (index - atCol) / this.boardModel.rows.length;
    return this.boardModel.rows[atRow][atCol];
  }

isFinished(): boolean{
  // check if game is finished
}

getBoardRow(index): string{
  return this.boardModel.rows[index];
}
```

I don't know if I made myself clear. Tic-tac-toe it's just an example. I want to know where should I put logic responsible for managing model properties? I read from documentation that all logic should be inside services. But for me in some cases it fits more to the model class (e.g., getters). Is it an anti-pattern to keep methods inside model class?

- inside model class (Board)
- inside service that uses this model (GameService)
- combine above two
- create services especially for that model (BoardService) with all needed functions and inject it into another service (GameService)

Answer (score 1):

Saying `I read from documentation that all logic should be inside services` is a bit misleading. Of course it really depends what is the logic doing and it absolutely isn't true that all logic should be in services.

For **Models**, it would make perfect sense to keep some logic within. A great example would be some `Modal` or `Notification` class, which would provide some functionality after initialization like `close`, `onClose`, and so on. Imagine you would need to close your notification through a service like `notificationService.close(<notificationUniqueId)`.

You talked about **components** in your example. The logic you presented is perfectly fine for a component. I would even say it is the best practice to put it into the component - it will make the integration with the UI cleaner and simpler and your code will be more manageable.

I do understand your struggle though. Sometimes it might happen that your UI logic will spread across multiple components. However, I would still stay away from putting it into a `Service`. Personally, I try to limit services to logic which `a) performs some API calls`, `b) formats data in some way` or `c) manages state and actions throughout the application`. In my recent projects, we implemented another Injectable type which we called `CommonUIHandler` - this subset of classes handled repetetive logic throughout components. But it created yet another level of abstraction and kept the traditional services from growing when it was not required.

I am sure if you search for `Angular design patterns`, you will find many valuable resources. An example worth mentioning might be https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-design-patterns-feature-services